# How to display error message on same login page by using php?

Tags: php, sql, authentication, sql-server-2012

I have developed a simple login script by using php and sql-server 2012 which consist of username, password, company code and google recaptcha with one submit button however, my code is working but it is printing error message in another page after clicking on submit button but i want it to print error message on same page and I only want user to login if everything is correct I do not want user to login if anything is incorrect any help will be highly appreciated feel free to edit my code if required ....

I am sharing my code except the designing part ....

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Simple login script using php</title>
 <form name="f1" action = "authentication.php" onsubmit = "return validation()" method = "POST">  
 <input type="text"  name="user">
 <input type="password"  name="pass">
  <input type="text"  name="pos">
 <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Lcl4eQgAAAAANX3sCFxUJETS6Q75uGRKZzzBjc"></div>
 <input type =  "submit" id = "btn" value = "Login"  name = "submit"/> 
 </body>
 </html>
```

I am sharing my php code too

```
 <?php 
 include("connection.php");
 
 if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])
 {
 $secretkey = "6Lcl4eQgAAAAAN4z4GC-UzfpLNYzlgoPINnHiovj";
 $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
 $response = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
 $url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secretkey&response=$response&remoteip=$ip";
 $fire = file_get_contents($url);
 $data = json_decode($fire);
 
         $loginok = true;
         if($data->success==true){
            echo " recaptcha success";
            $loginok = True;
         }
         else{
            echo  "please fill recaptcha" ;
            $loginok = FALSE;
         }
         }
         else{
            echo "Recaptcha error" ;
            $loginok = TRUE;
         }
         $uname = $_POST['user'];
         $upassword = $_POST['pass'];
         $Company_code = $_POST['pos'];
         
         if($Company_code==='CDSL'){
              echo "valid company code";
             $loginok = True;
         }
         else{
            echo "Invalid company code";
            $loginok = FALSE;
         }
         
         
         $res = sqlsrv_query($conn,"select* from user_master where UM_USERNAME='$uname'and um_pwd='$upassword' ");
         $result=sqlsrv_fetch_array($res);
         if($result==0)
         {
            echo "Invalid login credentials";
            
         //header("location:my-account.php");   // create my-account.php page for redirection 
            
         }
         else
         {
            echo "Login Success";
         
         }
     
     ?>
```

Comment: Read up on Ajax. Then you can submit the form in the background (using JavaScript) and then either present the response (error messages) on the same page (also using JavaScript) or redirect the user where you want them to go (also using JavaScript, if the auth was a successful)

Comment: **Warning!** Never store passwords in plain text! You should only store the password hashes, generated by [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php). Then on login, you fetch the user by only the username and verify the stored hash against the password using [password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). If you store them in plain text, you have compromised the users credentials (since anyone with access to the DB can see them, including you)

Comment: **Warning!** You're also **_wide open_** to [SQL injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection) attacks. You should use [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-prepare.php) with placeholders instead of injecting user data directly into the queries like that.

Comment: @M.Eriksson with the help of javascript i am able to get alert if username and password is empty how do print same alert message if username or password entered is incorrect

Comment: It's impossible to answer that question since I have _no idea_ what you've changed/done.

Comment: In the end, i want error message on my client side of invalid username or password @M.Eriksson

Comment: Yes, we already got that from your question so there's no need to repeat it.